# Outlook api trying to get all attachments with /attachments is returning ErrorInvalidAttachmentId

Tags: rest, outlook, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am new to Outlook and it's API, but from what I understand, I can get a list of attachments for a particular message.

I can get the message correctly with

```
client.api(`/users/${userId}/messages/${messageId}`)
```

But trying to fetch the attachments is returning an attachment ID error, although I want to fetch a list, not a single attachment.

```
client.api(`/users/${userId}/messages/${messageId}/attachments`)
```

```
'{"code":"ErrorInvalidAttachmentId","message":"The specified attachment Id is invalid."}'
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

---

Edit 1

For some reason, this works, meaning I can get the id and name.

```
`/users/${userId}/messages/${messageId}/attachments?$select=id,name`
```

But this doesn't:

```
`/users/${userId}/messages/${messageId}/attachments?$select=id,name,contentBytes`
```

```
"code":"BadRequest","message":"Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'contentBytes' on type 'microsoft.graph.attachment'."
```

Comment: See [GetAttachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) from Graph API.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev that's the do to get one attachment. What I am trying to achieve is to get all attachments from one message.